# Cross-validation in python sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using python sklearn library for doing classification of data. Following is the code I have implemented. I just want to ask, is this correct way of classifying? I mean can following code potentially remove all the biases? And, is it 10-k fold cross validation?

```
cv = cross_validation.ShuffleSplit(n_samples, n_iter=3, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=1, metric='minkowski',
       n_neighbors=2, p=2, weights='uniform')

knn_score = cross_validation.cross_val_score(knn,x_data_arr, target_arr, cv=cv)

print "Accuracy =", knn_score.mean()
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a 10-fold cross validation using ShuffleSplit you should put n_iter=10. However, as is shown in the  [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html): contrary to other cross-validation strategies, random splits do not guarantee that all folds will be different, although this is still very likely for sizeable datasets.
The other option if you want a 10fold cross-validation with different folds is using the function [KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html) with n_folds=10.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `cv` in `cross_validation.cross_val_score()` module means the iteration times you want to run. It gets a default value of `3` which means it will run cross validation 3 times by default. If you want to run a 10-folds cross validation, this param `cv` should equal to `10`. I hope this will help.